# django python cannot concatenate 'str' and '__proxy__' objects

Tags: python, django

I have `forms.py` in a Django app.

```
from django import forms
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy

class ComposeMessageForm(forms.Form):
ccc = reverse_lazy('user_api')
st = 'customSelectize:u_r,modelUrl:"'+ reverse_lazy('user_api') +'", choiceField:"username"'
user_receivers = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
    queryset=User.objects.all(),
    required=False,
    widget=forms.SelectMultiple(
        attrs={
            'data-bind': st,
            'placeholder': 'Select USERS'}))
```

When I run it I get

```
TypeError at /message/compose/

cannot concatenate 'str' and '__proxy__' objects
```

How can this be done? I have no idea what `__proxy__` object is.

`urls.py` is:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from rest_framework.urlpatterns import format_suffix_patterns
from django.contrib import admin
from msgin import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
                   url(r'^$', 'ms.views.home', name='home'),
                   url(r'^message/', include('msgin.urls')),
                   url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
                   url(r'^msgs/$', views.MessageList.as_view()),
                   url(r'^msgs/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$',
                       views.MessageDetail.as_view()),
                   url(r'^users/$', views.UserList.as_view(),
                       name='user_api'),
                   url(r'^users/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$',
                       views.UserDetail.as_view()),
                   url(r'^groups/$', views.GroupList.as_view(),
                       name='groups_api'),
                   url(r'^groups/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$',
                       views.GroupDetail.as_view()),
                   )
```

Answer (score 2):

Just put it inside str()

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
str(self.price) + " " + str(_("USD"))
```

Comment: alternatively import `ugettext` instead of `ugettext_lazy`

Answer (score 1):

there is no benefit to use `reverse_lazy` in the class definition, as cannot be "lazy"

you two options

1) use `reverse`

2) change your code as

```
class ComposeMessageForm(forms.Form):

    user_receivers = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.all(),
                                                    required=False)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ComposeMessageForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        st = 'customSelectize:u_r,modelUrl:"%s", choiceField:"username"' % reverse_lazy('user_api')
        self.fields['user_receivers'].widget=forms.SelectMultiple(attrs={'data-bind': st, 
                                                                         'placeholder': 'Select USERS'})
```

Comment: When i try to convert __proxy__ object to str i get this error        *** ImproperlyConfigured: The included urlconf 'ms.urls' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.

Comment: Probably You cannot use `reverse` in this case. See my option 2.

Answer (score 0):

**proxy** url is the url which resolves later, not at the time of calling `reverse_lazy()` func.  For this concrete case you can use simple `reverse()` function instead of lazy one.

But if want use `reverse_lazy()` when you should coerce proxy url to string:

```
st = 'customSelectize:u_r,modelUrl:"'+ str(reverse_lazy('user_api')) +'", choiceField:"username"'
```

or use string formatting:

```
st = 'customSelectize:u_r,modelUrl:"%s", choiceField:"username"' % reverse_lazy('user_api')
```

Comment: *** ImproperlyConfigured: The included urlconf 'ms.urls' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.

Comment: i get the above error though i have patterns in ms.urls